# Authenticated user loggouts after server restart

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have a node application and whenever I edit/update a `.js` file, users are logging out. I'm using `passport-local` with [express.io](http://express-io.org/).

Also I'm using `mongoose` and `socket.io`.

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.session({
        key: 'session',
        secret: '111'
    }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(flash());

});
```

How to make users log in forever?

---

**Solved** : [NodeJS + Express + Mongo Session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525001/nodejs-express-mongo-session-storage)

Comment: sessions aren't really supposed to be counted on after a server restart. Try looking into using cookies manually. sessions use cookies, but they aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep alive the session restarting node you need a session storage.
The default session storage stores data into ram and it's lost at every node restart.